Magento 2.4.5 FPT not showing properly with Configurable products on the Product details page
I have set FPT on all Products In my Magento (2.4.5-p2) store. But FPT is not showing properly with Configurable Products on the Product details page.
Please check the attached Image links...
https://i.imgur.com/PdeFTmY.png
https://i.imgur.com/GaOvime.png
Does anyone know, how to solve this Problem?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.
